# Why Horizontal Line in LaTex->dvi->ps->pdf is Thicker than LaTex->dvi->pdf?

Tags: rules, ps2pdf, dvips, dvipdf

I try to use this line in both chains of compiling:

```
\rule{6 cm}{0.02 cm}
```

but in LaTex->dvi->ps->pdf is thick even if I make 0.02cm lower while in LaTex->dvi->pdf is a nice slim line which I need. But unfortunately I have to use LaTex->dvi->ps->pdf chain in order to use hyperref package correctly, so how to fix that?

Note that I'm using TexStudio with MikTex library.

Comment: are you using `dvips -Ppdf`? It may help. How the rules get displayed will also depend on the viewer. I give some of the issues involved [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23067/how-does-pdf-or-pdf-viewer-define-a-rounding-rule-for-stroke-thickness/23077#23077) and give specifics for dvips with/without -Ppdf and also pdflatex, but not dvipdf.

Comment: @LevBishop Thanks!! this fixed the issue, you can put it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: As reference, see [How does PDF or PDF Viewer define a rounding rule for stroke thickness?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23067/5764)