# why are table lines are not black?

Tags: tables, color, lyx

my problem is that the lines of my tables (not all but most of them) are not really black but gray. Furthermore, the gray lines are also thinker than the other, which makes my tables look really bad.

I'm using Lyx and compiling with XeTeX.
I don't use any color in the document, so all color settings are default.
The rest of the document has a wonderful black

I tried to change the line color to green (following the Lyx help), for testing reasons and this worked:

```
\usepackage{colortbl}
\let\myHlineC\hline
\renewcommand{\hline}
{\arrayrulecolor{green}\myHlineC\arrayrulecolor{green}}
```

when I change 'green' to 'black', it's the same problem

when I define a new color 'newblack' with `\definecolor{newblack}{rgb}{0,0,0}` and change the color 'green' to 'newblack', it's also the same problem

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: I guess this is a problem with the pdf viewer.

Comment: See also [Box border lines not showing properly on PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11769).

Comment: you're right. 'preview' on mac has this problem but not adobe reader XI. thx