# How to create a table using tikz (or how to make a row in one column to have same text width as widest row in that column, etc.)?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Following conditions apply:

1. width of each column must not exceed 25mm
2. a less-wide row of a column must expand to widest row of same column (not to 25mm if the widest row is less than 25mm)

Note that using `varwidth` environment inside a `tikz` node creates extra space on the right of such node (which I couldn't remove, maybe you would) and makes text wrapping worse compared to when `text width` is used. But `text width` would expand the node from the get go to 25mm, even when text inside it is less wide than 25mm.

As a bonus, it would be nice to reduce thickness of node borders in places where they touch each other so the border of the table (as a whole) looks uniform in its thickness (and doesn't look more defined in some places compared to others).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset
  { every node/.style=
      { anchor=north west
      }
  }
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % 25mm ruler
    \path[draw=red,line width=1pt](0,0)--(25mm,0);

    % should span two columns
    \path node[draw](h)
      { header/title
      };

    \path node[draw](r1c1)at(h.south west)
      { row 1, col 1 (abcd)
      };

    \path node[draw](r1c2)at(r1c1.north east)
      { row 1, col 2 (abcdefg)
      };

    % width should match that of row 1, col 1
    %  (because row 1, col 1 is wider)
    \path node[draw](r2c1)at(r1c1.south west)
      { row 2, col 1
      };

    % width should match that of row 1, col 2
    %  (because row 1, col 2 is wider)
    \path node[draw](r2c2)at(r2c1.north east)
      { row 2, col 2 (ab)
      };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Another take

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset
  { every node/.style=
      { anchor=north west
      }
  }
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % should span two columns
    \path node[draw](h)
      { header/title
      };

    \path node
      [ draw,
        anchor=north east
      ](r1c1)at(h.south)
      { row 1, col 1 (abcd)
      };

    \path node[draw](r1c2)at(r1c1.north east)
      { row 1, col 2 (abcdefg)
      };

    % width should match that of row 1, col 1
    %  (because row 1, col 1 is wider)
    \path node
      [ draw,
        anchor=north east
      ](r2c1)at(r1c1.south east)
      { row 2, col 1
      };

    % width should match that of row 1, col 2
    %  (because row 1, col 2 is wider)
    \path node[draw](r2c2)at(r2c1.north east)
      { row 2, col 2 (ab)
      };

    % 25mm ruler
    \path[draw=red,line width=1pt](r1c1.north east)--($(r1c1.north east)+(25mm,0)$);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is `\matrix` for this, which has its own library.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/421922/how-to-draw-multiple-colored-bars-in-a-table https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231305/using-multirow-in-tables-created-with-a-tikz-matrix https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117554/tikz-matrix-color-entire-row https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415345/matrix-of-nodes-adjusting-the-lines ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this go in the right direction? If not, I will be happy to remove it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=2pt},
column 1/.style={nodes={align=right,anchor=east}},
column 2/.style={nodes={align=left,anchor=west}},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,row
sep=-\pgflinewidth,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,draw] (mat){
row 1, col 1 (abcd) & row 1, col 2 (abcdefg)\\
row 2, col 1 & row 2, col 2 (ab)\\
};
\draw ($(mat-1-1.south)!0.5!(mat-2-1.north)$) coordinate(aux1)
 ($(mat-1-1.east)!0.5!(mat-1-2.west)$) coordinate(aux2)
 (mat.west|-aux1) -- (mat.east|-aux1)
  (mat.north-|aux2) -- (mat.south-|aux2);
    \path node[draw,anchor=south,outer sep=0pt](h) at (mat.north-|aux2)
      { header/title
      };

    % 25mm ruler
    \path[draw=red,line width=1pt](mat-1-1.north east)--
    ($(mat-1-1.north east)+(25mm,0)$);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]