# Problem with losing some table borders when using colors

Tags: tables, color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make standard LaTex PDF output look good *on screen* as well](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/is-there-a-way-to-make-standard-latex-pdf-output-look-good-on-screen-as-well)

I'm trying to make colored rows in my table but for some reason table borders become invisible on some places when I apply color. For example the leftmost
vertical border becomes invisible when I open my pdf output. In fact, when I zoom in, then the top horizontal border becomes invisible, too.

I'm using MikTeX 2.9 and pdfLateX to produce output. It seems that the color for some reason covers the border on some places. Here is some code that produces the table which should have the leftmost vertical border but it doesn't.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.95} one&two\\
\rowcolor[gray]{0.95} three&four\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: One related question: [Box border lines not showing properly on PDF](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11769/1235).

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: I tried to use \usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor} but it didn't help in my case.

Comment: @Ivan: I'm pretty sure it's a viewer problem. Try and zoom in _really_ deep. Do you see all the lines then?

Comment: @Hendrik Yes, that's right. When I zoom in a lot then I can see all the lines.

Comment: @Ivan: Here's another tip: [Is there a way to make standard LaTex PDF output look good *on screen* as well](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/is-there-a-way-to-make-standard-latex-pdf-output-look-good-on-screen-as-well/9357#9357). Though it's not that great either. In my opinion, your question is the same as the 2nd point in the question I linked to. Do you agree?

Comment: @Hendrik I absolutely agree with you Hendrik. I think that the 2nd point in the link you provided is the same problem that I have. When I  open the document they are reffering to with my pdf viewer (Acrobat 8 professional) and zoom in, I can't see the leftmost table border either. One more indication that it's a viewer problem is that when my Latex editor (TeXworks) opens output pdf document in it's own viewer than everything looks fine.

Comment: @Ivan: OK, so I vote to close as a duplicate. If your question is closed, then people won't be able to post answers anymore, but will be pointed to that other question instead.