# Images not visible in PDF

Tags: graphics, pdf

I have a strange problem.
In some of the PDF readers, the images are not visible.
In others, the images are visible but font size of the text 
below the image for that page becomes really tiny.

Is it a problem with the images?

Comment: What format were the original images in? EPS, PDF, JPG, BMP, PNG, GIF, ... What is your compiler sequence: `latex`->`dvips`->`epstopdf`, or `pdflatex`?

Comment: Also, can you be more specific about the pdf readers?  Which pdf readers are in the first group, which are in the second group?

Comment: My first guess is png pictures with some transparency

Answer (score 2):

Interim answer: Maybe.

There are related questions that already have discussions and answers, e.g.

- [Acrobat doesn't recognize the images from pdflatex pdfs generated on Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28419/acrobat-on-windows-doesnt-recognize-the-images-from-pdflatex-pdfs-generated-on-u)
- [Is there a way to make standard LaTex PDF output look good *on screen* as well](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/is-there-a-way-to-make-standard-latex-pdf-output-look-good-on-screen-as-well)
- [Box border lines not showing properly on PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11769/box-border-lines-not-showing-properly-on-pdf).

If these do not solve your problem then to help folk answer your question some more pieces of information are needed such as those asked for in comments on your original question plus at least a couple more:

- What format were the original images in? EPS, PDF, JPG, BMP, PNG, GIF, ...
- What is your compiler sequence: `latex`->`dvips`->`epstopdf`, or `pdflatex`?
- It may also be helpful to show the LaTeX/TeX/LuaTeX/... code you have used to embed or create the diagram. The ideal would be a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).
- Which pdf readers are in the first group, which are in the second group?
- Does the output look correct with some viewers?, which?
- Is there any difference if you increase or decrease the viewer magnification?
- Is a printed version wrong or correct and, in either case how was it printed and to what (some printers can print pdf files directly, others will need the file processed by software on the computer).

As to the interim answer: you will have seen from the linked questions that an unexpected appearance can be caused by a viewer (but it is not usually wrong in every viewer at even the highest magnification and also wrong when printed) or by software that has created an image or embedded it into a file or post-processed the file so the problem could be with the images, but it could be something else or a combination of factors.