# Strange artifact when using xrightarrow

Tags: amsmath, arrows

When using xrightarrow, I sometimes gets weird artifacts on the arrow: it looks like the arrow is somewhat "doubled" in the middle. But this only happens when zoomed out; when I zoom in very close, the artifact disappears. This happens with all the PS and PDF viewers that I've tried.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\xrightarrow{\quad}$
\end{document}
```

Result (for SumatraPDF when compiled as a PDF, the results are similar if not identical for other viewers, PDF and PS alike):

[image: arrow]

Here I just put space to make the arrow longer, but it happens no matter what I put on the arrow. Is there a way around this issue, or an alternative to xrightarrow?

Comment: This is most likely due to pixel rounding errors in the PDF viewer. Note that the *extension* feature is made via overlaying two symbols.

Comment: @daleif As I mentioned, this happens (to some extent) in all the PDF viewers that I've tried: sumatrapdf, adobe reader, ps_viewer (which reads PDFs despite the name).

Comment: It also happens for PS viewers (sumatra, ghostscript...). Unless all these viewers have, by coincidence, the same bug, I think it's a problem with the way this arrow is produced, not a bug of the viewer.

Comment: The `\xrightarrow` generates a set of minus signs (by `\cleaders`) followed by arrow. It is possible, that the arrow has different hinting data than the minus. These "hinting" are used for rasterizing at low screen resolution. Or the hinting algorithm does artifact itself when there are overlapping characters.

Answer (score 0):

Well, compare with this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\begin{document}

\fontsize{4cm}{4cm}\selectfont

$\xrightarrow{\quad}$
\end{document}
```

no vissible bug.

Comment: ...Yes there is still a bug, if you zoom out. https://i.imgur.com/J9YYFYH.png And anyway how is that a solution? It completely destroys the document.

Comment: But it is still an artefact of the previewer. There is not much you can do about it other than try to change the font. It will not be detectable when printed on paper (because the resolution is much higher).

Comment: Are you saying that all viewers have, for some reason, the exact same bug?

Comment: Again it is not a bug! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132279/distortions-caused-by-latex

Comment: Do you mean these artifacts are wanted behavior?